# Please explain the technique used in this code to test Object Equality and Identity

Tags: c#, object-identity, object-equality

Please explain the technique used in this code to test Object Equality and Identity.

Better, if you can supply me any web-link/book-reference for detailed discussion.

```
[Serializable]
    public abstract class BusinessObject<T> : IBusinessObject where T : BusinessObject<T>
    {
        private int? requestedHashCode;

        public virtual int ID { get; set; }

        public virtual bool Equals(IBusinessObject other)
        {
            if (null == other || !GetType().IsInstanceOfType(other))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            {
                return true;
            }

            bool otherIsTransient = Equals(other.ID, default(T));
            bool thisIsTransient = IsTransient();
            if (otherIsTransient && thisIsTransient)
            {
                return ReferenceEquals(other, this);
            }

            return other.ID.Equals(ID);
        }

        protected bool IsTransient()
        {
            return Equals(ID, default(T));
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var that = obj as IBusinessObject;
            return Equals(that);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            if (!requestedHashCode.HasValue)
            {
                requestedHashCode = IsTransient() ? base.GetHashCode() : ID.GetHashCode();
            }
            return requestedHashCode.Value;
        }
}
```

What is a transient object?

Comment: Do you happen to have the code for the `Equals(object, object)` method?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, it's the static overload of Object.Equals...

Comment: `Equals(other.ID, default(T))` makes no sense at all to me - that is comparing an `int` to a `BusinessObject`...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Cheers, never used it before.

Comment: I might be wrong, but IMO the "technique" here is called "badly written barely functioning code".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- it first checks if `other` is an instance of the same type as the current object. If not, they're not equal
- it then performs a reference equality to check if `other` and the current object are the same instance. If they are, obviously they are equal
- If both `other` and the current object are transient (i.e. not yet persisted), they don't have an ID, so they can't be compared by ID. Instead, they are compared by reference. *(as noted by Marc Gravell in the comments, the test to check if the object is transient is broken; it doesn't make sense to compare an int to default(T))*
- Eventually, their IDs are compared; the objects are considered equal if they have the same ID

Comment: Can you supply me with any external reference?

Comment: What kind of external reference do you need? You can look at the [documentation for Object.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx), but the implementation itself is specific to your app domain...

Comment: Reference about database id-column based Equality/Identity testing in C#.

Comment: @Saqib, I don't know if there is any reference about that... it's not really a C# question: usually database entities with the same key are considered equal, because they're supposed to represent the same entity (otherwise, what would be the point of having a key in the first place?)

Answer (score 2):

I *think* what the code is trying to do is say "has it got an ID yet", i.e. a "transient" object might (if I read the code's intent correctly) be one that is not yet saved to the DB. Then equality is defined as:

- if it has an ID, does it match? (even for different instances of the same type)
- if it doesn't have an ID, is it the same object instance (reference)

unfortunately the implementation looks completely broken, as `Equals(ID, default(T))` is meaningless when `T` is something completely different (a `BusinessObject<T>`) - hence `default(T)` will always be `null` and `ID` will **never** be `null` (it is not nullable). So nothing will ever report as transient.

Additionally, this code:

```
if (null == other || !GetType().IsInstanceOfType(other))
```

is **hugely** inefficient. I suspect something involving `as` would be far preferable, but again: the code looks so... tortured... that I'm loathe to second-guess the intent.